# OpenGL Gaussian Kernel on 3D texture

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d-texture

I would like to perform a blur on a 3D texture in openGL. Since it is separable I should be able to do it in 3 passes. My question is, what would be the best way to cope with it?

I currently have the 3D texture and fill it using imageStore. Should I create other 2 copies of the texture for the blur or is there a way to do it while using a single texture?

I am already using glCompute to compute the mip map of the 3D texture, but in this case I read from the texture at level 0 and write to the one at the next level so there is no conflict, while in this case I would need some copy.

Comment: For a gaussian blur kernel I see no other way than having two data buffers (and alternate between the two for the three operations). Simpler kernels (such as box filter) can be implemented with a single pass.

Comment: do you mean bilateral filter? Can you show me an example of the box filter implemented in a single pass?

Comment: It's not really an answer to this question, so I'll leave it as a comment. And no, it's not a bilateral filter. The basic idea for the box filter is to calculate the filter value iteratively. Every time you push the filter one step further, add the next value to the filter and remove the last one that is not covered any more. Therefore, you need an array of the size of the filter radius (to keep track of the last values).

Comment: If you can provide some more detail on the problem maybe I can help more and edit my answer. Basically you can't do it in 3 passes, but depending on domain requirements, maybe there are other shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

In short it can't be done in 3 passes, because is not a 2D image. Even if kernel is separable.
You have to blur each image slice separately, wich is 2 passes for image (if you are using a 256x256x256 texture then you have 512 passes just for blurring along U and V coordinates). The you still have to blur along T and U (or T and V: indifferent) coordinates wich is another 512 passes. You can gain performance by using [bilinear filter](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/) and read values between texels to save some constant processing cost. **The 3D blur will be very costly.**

Performance tip: maybe you don't need to blur the whole texture but only a part of it? (the visible part?)

The problem wich a such **high number of passes**, is the number of interactions between GPU and CPU: drawcalls and FBO setup wich are both slow operations that hang the CPU (probably a [different API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_%28API%29) with low CPU overhead would be faster)

**Try to not separate the kernel:**

If you have a small kernel (I guess up to 5^3, only profiling will show the max kernel size) probably the fastest way is to NOT separate the kernel (that's it, you save a lot of drawcalls and FBO binding and leverage everything to GPU fillrate and bandwith).

**Spread work over time:**

Does not matter if your kernel is separated or not. Instead of computing a Gaussian Blur every frame, you could just compute it every second (maybe with a bigger kernel). Then you use as source of "continuos blurring data" the interpolation of the previouse blur and the next blur (wich is a 2x 3D Texture samples each frame, wich is much cheaper than continuosly blurring).

Comment: I need to blur the whole texture, even though it doesn't have to be a precise gaussian, i just want to take the values and spread them and having them fade (imagine a single voxel that starts to "emit" around it). Right now i implemented a normal blur with a 3x^3 kernel on 4 different 64^3 texture and iterated 8 times per frame and the performance were horrible (from 170fps to 15! on a gt540m). If there is a fast way to do a "wide blur" even in a very approximate way it would be perfect. I need this step to be as fast as possible. I also played with the work group size but nothing much changed

Comment: Added some info to my previous answer, basically you can try not separating the kernel, compute a blur only once every X frames and then interpolate 2 different blurs (bigger kernel will save work respect to small kernels applied many times). Also remember to remove all texture filtering (texelFecth will probably be a better idea than a 3D sample).